# Cannot connect to internet in VMWare WorkStation 10.0 - Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, server, vmware

I have `Ubuntu 12.04 Server` installed in `VMWare Workstation 10.0` on host `Windows 8.1`

```
/etc/network/interfaces
```

configuration is as follows.

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.171.132
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.171.1
```

and Network Adapter is set to `Custom: VMnet 8 (NAT)`

From `Windows`, my host, I can see that `VMNet 8` has `IPv4 : 192.168.171.1` that should be the gateway in `/etc/network/interfaces` and that is.

If I set it to `DHCP`, I can connect to internet from `VM` and get assigned an `IP` of `192.168.171.131`

But the problem is that I cannot connect to internet when I set it static.

Please tell me where I am getting wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set a static IP address in /etc/network/interfaces, you are also responsible to set up DNS nameservers. I suggest you try:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.171.132
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.171.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 192.168.171.1
```

Then get the system to re-read the file and use the changes:

```
sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0
```

Check:

```
ping -c3 www.google.com
```

Comment: Why you added 192.168.171.1 to dns-nameservers? What else we can use?

Comment: I added the gateway address because the router or other access point gets DNS nameservers from your internet service provider and is therefor a reliable fallback. You can use any DNS you wish. You might look into the package namebench. It tests and recommends fast DNS nameservers. https://code.google.com/p/namebench/

Comment: I get an error:
interface eht0 not configured.

Comment: @IgorG. I suggest you start your own new question and include all relevant details.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using 192.168.171.1, use 192.168.171.2.  In VM 10, if you click on Edit, Virtual Network Editor, select VM8, under VMnet Information, select NAT, click on NAT Settings and there you'll find what your GW IP address is set to.  When you find it, adjust your "eth0" gateway IP to that IP address.